# Compiling Java source file using classpath from generated jar file

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have several java source files in my current directory that I would like to generate a jar file of and use it in my classpath. So I took all my source files and compiled them to generate the associated .class files. I created the jar file as follows:

`jar cf abstractions.jar *.class`

This of course produced the jar file `abstractions.jar`

I then created the following test class called `Main.java`

```
import edu.stanford.cs.console.ConsoleWindow;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConsoleWindow console = new ConsoleWindow();
    }
}
```

I compiled this file from command line like this:

> javac -cp abstractions.jar Main.java

and I got the following error message saying that the package could not be found:

> Main.java:1: error: package edu.stanford.cs does not exist import
>   edu.stanford.cs.ConsoleWindow;
>                         ^ Main.java:5: error: cannot access ConsoleWindow
>                   ConsoleWindow console = new ConsoleWindow();
>                   ^   bad class file: ./abstractions.jar(ConsoleWindow.class)
>       class file contains wrong class: edu.stanford.cs.console.ConsoleWindow
>       Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Here is what the top of the ConsoleWindow class looks like:

```
/*
 * File: ConsoleWindow.java
 * ------------------------
 * This file implements the Console interface using a JFrame window.
 */

package edu.stanford.cs.console;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
```

I don't understand the error message. It mentions something about a subdirectory but I don't have any folders inside the jar.

How can I resolve the issue and get my program to compile?

Comment: There's a package typo, your class is `edu.stanford.cs.console.ConsoleWindow`, but your `Main` attempts to find it as `edu.stanford.cs.ConsoleWindow` .

Comment: @Berger Even after that fix I get the same error message

Comment: the typo is a minor issue, his command to build the jar file just needed different arguments.  His class files are in packages so they would be in subfolders.  The posted jar command would not include .class files recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jar command should include the folder(s) where the .class files are.
Does the generated .jar file even have files in it?  Rename .jar to .zip and look inside.

You should use ant to build jar files, like this:

```
  <target name="jar" description="build jar file">
    <jar destfile="abstractions.jar" includes="**/*.class" basedir="folder_where_you_put_class_files">
    </jar>
  </target>
```

Then you will get a proper jar file.

Or using jar move into the base folder where the .class files are and use:

```
jar -cf ../abstractions.jar *
```

Using *.class will only zip up files in the current folder (not recursive)

Note jar's help:

"If any file is a directory then it is processed recursively."

Comment: Yeah, the jar file was empty.